# Разновидности игры "Баше". Выигрышные алгоритмы для компьютера

Tags: алгоритм, любой-язык

Добрый вечер. 
Друзья, многие из вас наверняка слышали, или играли в игру "Баше".

---

Суть игры, классический случай:

> 1. Играют двое.
>     На столе лежит N предметов, игроки по очереди берут от 1 до k предметов.
>     Проигравшим, считается игрок, взявший последний предмет.

Думаю теперь всё понятно, и большинство поняли, о чем я говорю.

---

Для классического случая, и двух модернизированных(о  них ниже), нужно составить алгоритм хода, при котором компьютер будет выигрывать человека(не знающего выигрышных алгоритмов).

Не стандартные случаи:

> 2. Играют двое. 
>     На столе лежит N предметов, игроки по очереди берут любое количество предметов, но не больше - "2 * (сколько взял предыдущий игрок)", ноль брать нельзя. Победителем считается игрок, взявший последний предмет.

> 3. Играют двое.
>     На столе лежит N предметов, игроки по очереди берут любое количество предметов, но не больше, чем взял предыдущий, ноль брать нельзя.
>
>    Победителем считается игрок, взявший последний предмет.

Как я уже говорил, для каждого случая, нужно составить алгоритм, при котором компьютер будет выигрывать юзера.

---

Для начала нужно определить 100% выигрышные позиции для каждого случая.
Выигрышная позиция, это та позиция, которую ты оставляешь после своего хода, и побеждаешь при любых ходах соперника.

1 случай:
Все выигрышные позиции стоят на местах - (k+1) -> 2(k+1) -> 3(k+1) -> etc.

2 случай:
Все выигрышные позиции - это числа фибоначчи -  1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, etc

3 случай:
Все выигрышные позиции - это степени двойки - 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, etc.

---

Выигрышные позиции определили. Следующая(и окончательная) задача, составить алгоритм хода компьютера.

Мне удалось написать процедуру хода только для первого случая, с остальными я прошу помощи.

Я использовал паскаль, вы можете писать на любом удобном вам языке.

**1 случай:**

```
procedure step(var n,k,a:integer);
begin // n - кол-во предметов на столе, k - максимально можем взять, a - наш ход(сколько берем)
if n mod k+1 = 1 then a:=1+random(k)
    else if n mod k+1 = 0 then a:=k
        else a:=(n mod k+1)-1
end;
```

**2 случай:** нет идей, прошу помощи.

**3 случай:**

```
procedure step(var n,a:integer, var b:integer);
// а - взял предидущий игрок, b - наш ход.
begin
if n mod 2 = 1 then b:=1; //если нам оставили нечетное, начинаем брать по 1 и выигрываем.
    else 
        if a >= n div 2 then b:=n //если предыдущий игрок взял больше половины, забираем всё остальное вместе с последней.
            else ??????????? 
end;
```

С третьим случаем вопрос остаётся открытым, моё вариант побеждает не постоянно.

Прошу помощи в реализации 2го и 3го случая. Спасибо за внимание)

Comment: а в 2 и 3 пункте какой 1 ход? Особенно в 3.

Comment: первый ход - любое количество предметов, все сразу взять нельзя, конечно. (2-3 случаи). 
Так же, ходить первыми можем и мы, думаю, стоит это учитывать.

Comment: любое? забираю всё и ладно

Answer (score 2):

Данные задачи относятся к классическим задачам на теорию игр, по ним написано множество статей. Идея вычисления выигрышного хода основана на теоремах Шпрага-Гранди и Бутона. Для ответа на вопрос "куда ходить" нужно вычислить состояния игры. Тут игра НЕ распадается на сумму 2 других, поэтому достаточно использовать рекурсию. При этом состояние игры описывается 2 числами - `{количество оставшихся, взято на том ходу}`. Составим функцию для примера 2 (3 задача очень мутная), считаю что первый ход всегда 1:

```
int Val[1000][1000];



int func(int Count, int prevV){
    if (Val[Count][prevV] != -1)
        return Val[Count][prevV];
    char Z[10000];
    memset(Z,0,sizeof(Z));
    for (int i=1;i<=min(2*prevV,Count);i++)
        Z[  func(Count - i,i) ] = 1;
    for (int i=0; ; i++)
        if (!Z[i]){
            Val[Count][prevV] = i;
            return i;
        }

}

int calcStep(int Count, int prevV){
    if (!func(Count,prevV))
        assert(false);
    for (int i=1; ;i++)
        if (!Val[Count - i][i]) return i;
}

int main() {
    for (int i=1;i<1000;i++)
        for (int j=1;j<1000;j++)
            Val[i][j] = -1;
    int count;
    int d;
    int prev;
    prev = 1;
    cin >> count;
    cout <<"Test "<<func(count - 1,1)<<endl;
    while (count){
        cin>>d;
        if (d > 2*prev)
            assert(false);
        count -=d;
        cout << func(count,d)<<endl;
        prev = calcStep(count,d);
        count -= prev;
        cout << count<<" "<<prev << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Дальше просто делаем все рекурсивные вычисления. Демонстрационная программа.
Ссылка на почитать http://e-maxx.ru/algo/sprague_grundy